# Need to set Default value in Kofax Capture Scan , Create Batch popup

Tags: kofax

I am using Kofax Capture scan 10.o
Requirement is to set the default value in Create batch window setting pages per batch to 20 instead of 0 everytime the user open this window.

Please let me know how this will be possible.
I am not aware of how to customize this window.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe it is possible to set this programmatically.  However you could write a custom Scan panel that pops up a warning if a batch is trying to close without 20 pages.  This would essentially do the same thing as the product functionality, but then the user doesn't have to enter the number each time.

To write a custom panel you would need to look into the Capture API documentation and the sample installed to CaptureSV\Source\Sample Projects\StdCust\OCXPanel.

Update:
Daniel is correct in saying that "Pages per batch" is not a batch field.  It is a property of the batch that must be set on the Create Batch dialog.  To my knowledge this cannot be set programmatically: I did not see a mention of it in the API guide.  [image: Create Batch dialog]

Actual batch fields *can* have a default set as you can see in the Batch Class Properties dialog below.  It can either be an explicit string or one of the curly brace auto replace values.  And yes, you should be able to modify them programmatically from a workflow agent.  Or if using KTM, enable foldering in the KTM project and then batch fields are mapped to the root folder and can be modified in KTM validation or from script in any KTM module.
[image: Batch Class Properties dialog]

Comment: True, batch fields dont take a default value.

Comment: @varun: false, batch fields DO take default values. Problem is that "pages per batch" is not a batch field.

Comment: That's interesting.. Since it was defined at batch creation time and took the value at batch level, I always viewed it as a batch value. What is it then? And how would one assign a value to a batch field? Workflow agent?

Comment: Updated answer to address the difference between the "pages per batch" property and true batch fields.